# React: How to validate inputs upon submit in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am making an expense tracker that makes a list of expenses upon submit based of the values in an input. Right now I am wanting to validate if the inputs are empty or not and if they are I want alert the user that they need to fill in the required field. So far I've done this but can't get it to work so far

```
const addExpenses = () => {



 setExpense(prevState => {
      return [
        ...prevState,
        {
          id: uuidv4(),
          name: expenseName,
          amount: expenseAmount,
          type: expenseType
        }
      ];
    });
    if(expenseName === '') return;
    setExpenseName("");
    setExpenseAmount("");
  };

return (
    <>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Expense name</label>
        <input
          value={expenseName}
          onChange={updateExpenseName}
          type="text"
          className="expense-name"
          placeholder="Expense name"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Expense amount</label>
        <input
          value={expenseAmount}
          onChange={updateExpenseAmount}

          type="number"
          className="expense-amount"
          placeholder="Expense amount"
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: where is the method `updateExpenseName`?

Comment: I don't see anything that triggers a submit

Comment: Read some tutorials and documentation for popular React form validation libraries.

Answer (score 1):

First things first use some basic HTML validation.
like bellow, I use a **form** and **required** in my **input**. By using this you cannot submit the form keeping anything empty

```html
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input
    required
    type="text"
    className="expense-name"
    placeholder="Expense name"
  />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

but still, there are some validation like if use give any space so for that in your **handleSubmit** add some logic like bellow

```
const handleSubmit = () =>{
    //as example i am only showing for expenseName
    if(expenseName.trim().length === 0){
        alert('Wrong Input');
    }else{
        //do your job
    }
}
```

**full-example**

https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-cherry-qt1qw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

For detect if input is empty :

```js
if(!(input == null || input == '')) {
 // Continue
}else{
  // Input is empty!
}
```

This example is not optimised, I know, but it works.